# Swift Dictionary access value through subscript throws Error

Tags: swift, dictionary, collections

Accessing a Swift `Dictionary` value through subscript syntax is gives error `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`

Here is the code

```
class Model {

    struct Keys {
        static let type :String = "type" //RowType
        static let details :String = "details"
    }

    var type :RowType = .None
    var details :[Detail] = []

    init(with dictionary:Dictionary<String, Any>) {

        if let type = dictionary[Keys.type] as? String {
            self.type = self.rowTypeFromString(type: type)
        }

        if let detailsObj = dictionary[Keys.details] as? Array { //Error : Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'


       }
    }

}
```

if i remove the type casting `as? Array` at the end of optional-binding it compiles fine

I am expecting the value of `details` key to be an `Array`, I know that i can use `[String,Any]` instead of `Dictionary<Key, Value>`, What is causing the issue ?

Comment: `as? Array` – as an array of *what* exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved by explicitly specifying the `Type` of objects the array contains, In my case it was `Array<[String:Any]>`

```
if let detailsObj = dictionary[Keys.details] as? Array<[String:Any]> { //we should also specify what type is present inside Array


}
```

Credits: @Hamish, @Dávid Pásztor

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Array doesn't work like NSArray, you explicitly need to tell what type your array is storing.

If you want to store `Detail` objects in it, the proper syntax is `Array<Detail>` or simply [`Detail]`

```
if let detailsObj = dictionary[Keys.details] as? Array<Detail> {

}
```